# Preprocess Javascript to remove object property names quotes

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I would like to preprocess javascript property names to convert them from

```
{
  'extension': object,
  'config': {id: 1}
}
```

to

```
{
  extension: object,
  config: {id: 1}
}
```

I know that they mean the same thing for JS, but they are not the same thing for Google Closure Compiler on Advance mode where the quoted property is left untouched while the unquoted might be changed to

```
{
  a: object,
  b: {a: 1}
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right solution to my original problem which is:

Developers are working on an extension based on an API. This API is defined by quoted property names. The code on my side is compiled and mangled. I would like to take their code, remove all the quotes and compile both my code and the developer code on advance and at the end there should be no 'extension' string in the final .js

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to remove quotes, Prettier has options to remove quotes from properties:

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quote-props

Comment: seems nice. Will look at it. Thanks.